# Full Text Search with constantly updating data

Tags: c#, mongodb, full-text-search, lucene.net

I'm working on a web application in ASP.NET MVC which involves a fairly complex (I think) search situation.  Basically, I have a bunch of entries with a title and content.  These are the fields that I want to provide full-text search for. The catch is that I also keep track of a rating on these entries (like up-vote/down-vote).  I'm using MongoDB as my database, and I have a separate collection for all these votes.  I plan on using a map/reduce function to turn all of the documents in the votes collection into a single "score" for the article.  When I perform a search, I want the article's score to be influential on the rankings.

I've been looking at many different full-text search services, and it looks like all the cool kids are using Lucene (and in my case, Lucene.NET).  The problem is that since the score is not part of the document when I will first create the index, I don't know how I would set up Lucene.  Each time somebody votes for an article, do I need to update the Lucene index?  I'm a little lost here.

I haven't written any of this code yet, so if you have a better way to solve this problem, please share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is that since the score is not part of the document when I
>   will first create the index, I don't know how I would set up Lucene

What the problem? Just use default value for rating/votes (probably 0) and later when peoples will vote up update it.

> Each time somebody votes for an article, do I need to update the
>   Lucene index?

No, this can be expensive and slow. In your app probably will be huge volume of updates and lucene can be slow when you will do often flushes to the disk. In general almost for any full text search real time updates not so important as full text search. So i suggest following strategy:

Solution #1:

1.Create collection in mongodb where you will store all updates related to lucene:

```
{
  _id,
  title,
  content,
  rating, //increment it 
  status(new, updated, delete) // you need this for lucene
}
```

2.After this you need create tool that will process all this updates in background (once per 10 minutes for example). Just take in the mind that you need flush data to the disc, say, after 10000 of lucene update/insert/delete to make lucene index updates fast.

With above solution your data can be stale for 10 minutes, but inserts will be faster.

Solution #2:

1. Send async messages for each update related to lucene.
2. Handle this messages and update lucene each time once message come
3. Async handling very important, otherwise it can affect application performance.

I would go with #1, because it is should be less expensive for the server.

Choose what you like more.

Comment: Basically create a queue.  I like it.

Answer (score 0):

Go straight to the MongoDB or the database and increment and decrement the votes. You have to be constantly updating the database in my view. Don't need to get complicated. Something is added, add something in the database. update, insert, delete all the time if there is a change in the website. Changes need to be tracked and the tracking place is in the mongodb or the sql database. For searching fields, use the mongodb field search parameters and combine all the fields that it returned and rank them yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I think you probably are right about incrementing and decrementing the votes.  However, I need more advanced searching than is available mongodb.  Stemming and phrase-search are available in full-text search tools, but not in simple mongodb queries.

Comment: It just matters how detailed you want to go with full text searching. Split query into words, pull all entries for each word and rank them and get the document that has the most query words. It is a matter of choice.